# How to Make a Status Field Bydefault Enable in Magento Form?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Following is my Form Field Code.

```
$fieldset->addField('status','select', 
    array(
    'label'  => Mage::helper('synclogin')->__('Eshot Status'),
    'name'   => 'status',
    'values' => array(
        array(
        'value' => 0,
        'label' => Mage::helper('synclogin')->__('Disabled'),
        ),
         array(
        'value' => 1,
        'label' => Mage::helper('synclogin')->__('Enabled'),
       ),
    ),
    )
);
```

How to Make a Status Field Bydefault Enable in Magento Form?

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldset->addField('status','select', 
    array(
    'label'  => Mage::helper('synclogin')->__('Eshot Status'),
    'name'   => 'status',
    'value'  => '1',
    'values' => array(
        array(
        'value' => 0,
        'label' => Mage::helper('synclogin')->__('Disabled'),
        ),
         array(
        'value' => 1,
        'label' => Mage::helper('synclogin')->__('Enabled'),
       ),
    ),
    )
);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain the changes you have made, both in terms of what they are and why they answer the question.